# Vertically fade image to transparency using Python PIL library

Tags: python, png, transparency, python-imaging-library

I have looked at tutorials, other stackoverflow questions and the PIL documentation itself, but I'm still still not sure how to do it.

I'd like to start fading an image vertically at approximately 55% down the y-axis, and have the image completely transparent at approximately 75%. It's important that I preserve the full height of the image, even though the last 25% or so should be completely transparent.

Is this possible to do with PIL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure it's doable.

Let's assume that you're starting off with an image with no transparency (because otherwise, your question is ambiguous).

Step 1: Add an alpha plane. That's just [`putalpha`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#image-putalpha-method), unless you're dealing with a non-planar image, in which case you'll need to convert it to RGB or L first.

Step 2: Iterate through the pixels you want to change by using the pixel array returned by [`load`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#image-load-method) (or `getpixel` and `setpixel` if you have to deal with ancient versions of PIL).

Step 3: There is no step 3. Unless you count saving the image. In which case, OK, step 3 is saving the image.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('bird.jpg')
im.putalpha(255)
width, height = im.size
pixels = im.load()
for y in range(int(height*.55), int(height*.75)):
    alpha = 255-int((y - height*.55)/height/.20 * 255)
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,)
for y in range(y, height):
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (0,)
im.save('birdfade.png')
```

Here the alpha drops off linearly from 255 to 0; it you want it to drop off according to a different curve, or you're using RGB16 instead of RGB8, or you're using L instead of RGB, you should be able to figure out how to change it.

---

If you want to do this faster, you can use numpy instead of a Python loop for step 2. Or you can reverse steps 1 and 2—construct an alpha plane in advance, and apply it all at once by passing it to `putalpha` instead of `255`. Or… Since this took under half a second on the biggest image I had lying around, I'm not too worried about performance, unless you have to do a million of them and you want a faster version.

Comment: Sorry, won't be able to put your answer into practice for a few hours, but looks good. I'll update shortly. Also, I forgot to mention that the images (there will be quite a few, so efficiency would be nice) are all jpegs, but jpeg doesn't support transparency, so needs to be saved as png, right?

Comment: @RTF: Right, you will need to save to PNG (or something else that supports transparency). Meanwhile, how many is "quite a few"? And how big are the files? Spending an extra hour coding and debugging something more complex to save yourself 10 seconds of runtime is not worthwhile; if it saves you an extra 3 hours of runtime every month for the next 3 years, that's a different story…

Comment: Could be a few hundred images, pulled from a web service one at a time, about 400k-500k each (resulting pngs will be ~1.75mb, much larger than I'd like, but I have no choice if I want the transparency). As it happens, each image request needs at least 1 sec between requests to prevent me being throttled, and right now I'm sleeping for the majority of that. So, I'll take this rather than pull in another library (numpy).

Answer (score 3):

Using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import Image

img = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('RGBA')
arr = np.array(img)
alpha = arr[:, :, 3]
n = len(alpha)
alpha[:] = np.interp(np.arange(n), [0, 0.55*n, 0.75*n, n], [255, 255, 0, 0])[:,np.newaxis]
img = Image.fromarray(arr, mode='RGBA')
img.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm gonna go with abarnerts solution without the need for numpy. I don't mind sacrificing the performance gain that numpy will bring and it means I don't have to pull in another library.

Comment: I think you could make this slightly simpler and faster by just using numpy to build an A plane to pass to `putalpha`. From a quick test (although I got the arguments to interp wrong because I'm an idiot, so the result was incorrect), .91s for `setpixel`, .36s for `im.load`, .06s for your version, .05s for `putalpha`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code of [@abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235788/2603230) a bit if you want to fade image which already had a transparent background ([detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40948710/2603230)):

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('bird.jpg')
width, height = im.size
pixels = im.load()
for y in range(int(height*.55), int(height*.75)):
    for x in range(width):
        alpha = pixels[x, y][3]-int((y - height*.55)/height/.20 * 255)    # change made here
        if alpha <= 0:
            alpha = 0
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,)
for y in range(y, height):
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (0,)
bg.save('birdfade.png')
```