# How to fade an image with transparency from the top using Python (Pillow)

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble figuring out how to fade an image that has transparency from the top, I know something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075431/14730950) works, however, manipulating it to fade from the top instead of the bottom is proving quite difficult. I was wondering if I could get some help.

Current code for fading images (towards the bottom, not top, I need top and bottom) looks like:

```
def image_fade(im: Image, fade_start, fade_finish, from_top: bool = False):
    width, height = im.size
    pixels = im.load()
    
    fade_range = list(range(int(height*fade_start), int(height*fade_finish)))
    
    if from_top:
        for y in fade_range:
            for x in range(width):
                alpha = int((y - height*fade_start)/height/(fade_finish - fade_start) * 255)
                alpha = 0 if alpha <= 0 else alpha
                pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,)

        for y in range(height, y):
            for x in range(width):
                pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (0,)

    else:
        for y in fade_range:
            for x in range(width):
                alpha = pixels[x, y][3]-int((y - height*fade_start)/height/(fade_finish - fade_start) * 255)
                alpha = 0 if alpha <= 0 else alpha
                pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,)

        for y in range(y, height):
            for x in range(width):
                pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (0,)
            
    return im
```

Fade start and finish should be equal on both sides, meaning if we pass the parameters `0.7, 0.9` for fade_start and fade_finish, the top half should be `(1-fade_finish), (1-fade_start)`, or `(0.1, 0.3)`

From something like:

[image]

I am trying to get something like (where the background is transparent, not white, say I want 10% of the top and bottom faded):

[image]

Comment: [mre] please... and a clear demo of what you want, vs what you don't want.

Comment: How are your `fade_start/finish`variables supposed to work, please? What is 0.1 or 0.3 of what? Is it the percentage opacity? Is your image fully transparent at top edge and fully transparent at bottom edge?

Comment: Okay @MarkSetchell, I edited the function again. So pretty much the way it's supposed to work is if I specify flow_up, it needs to fade from the top, if not, it fades from the bottom. Currently, the bottom script (when from_top is false) works fine in terms of what I'm trying to achieve. From start (0.7) to (0.9), the alpha level goes from 255 to 0, and then anything past that (0.9+) is automatically 0. I need it to do the same thing on the other side if from_top is true basically.

Comment: What is `flow_up`, please? And it's still unclear (to me) what you mean by *"0.7 of something"*?

Comment: `flow_up`/`from_top` is the param being passed. If `from_top` is True, the image will return the image passed with a fade from the top. 0.7 refers to the percentage of where on the image (vertically) the fade begins. So 0.7 just refers to starting at 70% at the y pos for the img. @MarkSetchell

Comment: So why do you need the 0.9 as well?

Comment: 0.9 is at what point the image should be completely faded, meaning instead of the fade happening gradually from 70% to 100%, the image is completely transparent at and after 90%. If from_top is enabled, it should mock the same thing but instead of being transparent after the `fade_finish` param, it should gradually become more visible until that param.

Comment: I still don't understand your question, sorry. Your diagram shows an image faded at the top **and** the bottom, yet your code seems to only do one **or** the other, not both?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ah I see the confusion, sorry, so the function is called twice, once to fade the bottom, once to fade the top, since when I was debugging I needed to disect them separately: img = image_fade(pull_img, 0.7, 0.9), img = image_fade(pull_img, 0.1, 0.3, True)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of doing this. Here is one method. Basically, in order to make an image transparent, you need to create a greyscale  alpha/transparency image which is black where you want the image to be transparent and white where you want it to be opaque. Then push that into your image as an alpha layer and save to a format that supports transparency (PNG, TIFF) as opposed to JPEG.

So, starting with this image:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image and get dimensions
im = Image.open('RandomColouredSquares.png')
w, h = im.size

# Make a linear gradient and resize to match width of input image and 10% of its height
gradient = Image.linear_gradient('L')
gradient = gradient.resize((w,int(h/10)))
```

`gradient` looks like this:

[image]

```
# Make a new, fully opaque transparency layer (i.e. white) to match input image size
alpha = Image.new('L', (w,h), 'white')

# Paste the gradient into the top-left, then flip top to bottom and paste again
alpha.paste(gradient)
alpha = alpha.transpose(Image.Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
alpha.paste(gradient)
```

`alpha` looks like this:

[image]

```
# Now push that alpha layer into the original and save
im.putalpha(alpha)
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use something like the post I linked? Where its strictly just piggying off of pixel manipulation. For reference, I edited the main post to include the code I'm working with right now

Comment: Yes, but processing images with `for` loops is not very desirable or efficient in Python. And you almost certainly don't want to be processing the RGB channels as well, since they are unaffected by the transparency change.

Comment: I see, I think collectively it still takes under a second per image generation for what I'm trying to do

Comment: So for this method, how would I go about dealing with images that already have an alpha channel, say the image is an arbitrary png file, wherever the transparency is not 255, this method would most likely error?

Comment: I wrote my answer to deal with the original question which didn't mention any existing transparency. As it stands, it won't error out, it will just ignore the existing transparency.

Comment: The original post was about fading an image that already has transparency, I never changed the title or the original question

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I missed that.