# How to fade image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which is doing the fade on the bottom only and also it will fade almost half of the image. How can I make it work to only fade only 10% of the image at bottom and top:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('1.jpg')
im.putalpha(255)
width, height = im.size
pixels = im.load()
for y in range(int(height*.55), int(height*.75)):
    alpha = 255-int((y - height*.55)/height/.15 * 255)
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,)
for y in range(y, height):
    for x in range(width):
        pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (0,)
im.save('1.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you took the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235664/vertically-fade-image-to-transparency-using-python-pil-library), you should know the meaning of the function. To solve your problem, just need to modify it a little:

```py
im = Image.open('1.png')
im.putalpha(255)
width, height = im.size
pixels = im.load()

def fade_image(image, p1, p2, flow_up=False):
    fade_range = list(range(int(height*p1), int(height*p2)))
    fade_range = fade_range[::-1] if flow_up else fade_range
    for y in fade_range:
        if flow_up:
            alpha = int((y - height*p1)/height/(p2-p1) * 255)
        else:
            alpha = 255-int((y - height*p1)/height/(p2-p1) * 255)
        for x in range(width):
            pixels[x, y] = pixels[x, y][:3] + (alpha,) 

fade_image(pixels, 0.9, 1. , flow_up=False)
fade_image(pixels, 0  , 0.1, flow_up=True)
im.save('1.png')
```

Here, I assume that for 10% on top of the image, you need to fade it in the up direction, so decreasing the alpha linearly from 255 to 0 from pixel index `0.1 * height` to `0`. I removed the two last "for loop" because, in the other StackOverflow question, it required erasing the bottom of the fade.